# JUnit test is getting executed when it's not supposed to

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-test

I am new to `JUnit`. Following is my class hierarchy where classes at top and bottom of the hierarchy has `@Test` methods. When I execute whole bunch, `ConverterBaseEnquiryTest` which is at middle of the hierarchy is also getting executed. (That's my guess because I see exception in `surefire` reports with this name).

And I am getting initialization errors from `ConverterBaseEnquiryTest` because it wasn't supposed to be executed. Is there any way to figure out why this is happening?

Following is my hierarchy:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { 
    "classpath:spring/test-default-context.xml"
})
@TransactionConfiguration( transactionManager="profile.transactionManager", defaultRollback=false )
@Ignore
public class BaseCommonTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {


abstract public class ConverterBaseTest<F,T> extends BaseCommonTest {
    // ...
}

public class ConverterBaseEnquiryTest<F, T> extends ConverterBaseTest<Enquiry, T> {
    // ...
}

public class EnquiryToDvsMedicareRequestConverterTest extends ConverterBaseEnquiryTest<Enquiry, DvsMedicareRequest> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To elaborate on the exception: When I will run test from EnquiryToDvsMedicareRequestConverterTest, it will satisfy both of the <F, T> type requirement. But when ConverterBaseEnquiryTest is run it do not have both types supplied. And thats where it throws exception.

Comment: Please post the commands you use to run your tests as well as the log from the run. The configuration of the surefire plugin from your pom would also help.

Comment: Side note: many people say that you really should stay away from using "inheritance" as a mean to "share common code" for unit tests. I partially agree to that; and my hint to you: even when it requires "more coding"; try to avoid complicated "inheritance" models for your test code ... at least initially; and only start using such things when you are more profound in the "unit testing topic".

Comment: I am using maven commands: mvn test

Comment: Yes Jägermeister, I agree that atleast inheritance should be avoided in JUnit tests. Its getting complicated day by day to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because `@Ignore` annotation is not inheritable, so JUnit will execute tests in subclasses. (Although posting the stacktrace would help us).

This means you will also need to place `@Ignore` on all subclasses.

Alternatively, to save you from that, you could perhaps use [`@IfProfileValue`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/IfProfileValue.html) (which is inherited) on the base-class to disable the tests. This is a Spring annotation supported by the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Comment: Simply adding @Ignore to classes in the middle of the hierarchy did the work. Thanks Jonathan.